# Serial upvoting reversed: I lost 0 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Some goofball has been serial upvoting me for the past two days, and while I've sent out hunting parties to find the miscreant and taze him bro until he quits, I did notice an extreme oddity:

When the serial upvoting was reversed, instead of losing the 90-100 rep I was expecting to lose, I lost zero.

[image]

I know that I didn't actually lose any rep, since before "Serial upvoting reversed" I had 40,119 reputation, and now I have 40,179 reputation after having had six answers upvoted afterward.

Comment: Guess: The serial up votes didn't affect your reputation. It looks like you had a lot of upvotes yesterday (enough to get above the rep cap). So when the upvotes were reversed you still had enough rep to hit the rep cap

Comment: That could be. I had a LARGE number of non-serial upvotes yesterday.

Comment: @hims056 What makes you think this is a dupe?

Comment: @hims056 Maybe so, but it isn't _clearly_ explained there. The explanation given below by Lucifer is much better.

Comment: @DannyBeckett -  *all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed*

Comment: @hims056 That does not explain how the result is a rep reversal of 0.

Comment: @FEichinger: Now it does. :) Amazing the power of editing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The day you got serially upvoted (yesterday - 28-06-2013), your reputation was **232**; 200 from regular upvotes, 2 accepted answers and 2 reputation from accepting an answer. You hit the daily rep cap. After this happened, somebody started serially upvoting you; so, you didn't earn a single reputation point from those upvotes.

The automated script, having detected such serial voting, simply reversed all the upvotes. As you hadn't earned any reputation from the serial upvotes, you didn't lose anything when the action was reversed.

Disclaimer: I am saying all of this by looking at your [profile](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton?tab=reputation).

Comment: It should at least say 0 or something.

Comment: @ColeJohnson yes, but I would say it is either a bug or `status-bydesign`

Comment: In the same way that an upvote after hitting the rep cap doesn't show up as a zero, neither does the reversal. It indicates that **no action was taken** as opposed to showing "you gained/lost zero rep"... Makes more sense to me...

Comment: @Lix oh, I forgot to mention that part in my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way as the upvotes you received after hitting the rep cap on the previous day don't show up with a zero, neither does the reversal.

It's consistent with any action that doesn't really affect your reputation. It makes more sense to me to leave it blank rather than placing a zero there saying:

> `"You've lost/gained 0 reputation"`