# Does serial-downvote-reverse refunding affect the daily cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186623/serial-upvoting-reversed-i-lost-0-reputation/186625#186625), but I don't get it. And [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137236/what-effect-does-serial-downvoting-have-on-my-rep-cap) seems to fit better; but ... well, no answers there.

Yesterday, I was victim to some [serial-downvoter-sock-puppet-clown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6559239/utkarsh-dubey); so *Achievements* has a long list of -2 entries for yesterday.

Today, as to be expected, *Achievements*, shows many +2; all fine.

But what I am wondering: right now I got a daily total of 103; and now I am wondering if all those +2 will count for the daily cap **today** or not.